# Checking whether an object is uniquely referenced, using a weak reference to it

Tags: swift, reference, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Consider this code:

```
class EmptyClass {}

var strongReference = EmptyClass()
weak var weakReference = strongReference

print(isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC(&strongReference)) // true
print(isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC(&weakReference))   // false
```

I would expect both print statements to print `true`. Does this mean it's impossible to check whether an object is uniquely referenced if I only have a weak reference to it? And is this a bug, or is it expected?

Comment: Readers might also be interested in the discussion on the swift-users mailing list: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160627/002365.html.